# git ignore everything with "secret" in path or filename

Tags: git

I have project with secrets scattered across sub-folders and files. I want to make sure they don't enter git repository.

Anything with `secret` in path of filename should be ignored

```
#to be ignored
project/secrets/mypasswords.txt
project/module/my_secret.token
project/.env_secters.sh
secret/all-subfolders/should/be-ignored
```

So I tried `project/.gitignore`

```
!.gitignore
.*secret.*
**/.*secret.*/**
```

but gitt still offer to add subfolder files

Comment: How about `**/*secret*/**` ? Also it looks like your `.gitignore` needs to be outside the `project` folder

Comment: With `.*` are you trying to construct a regular expression that matches everything? But patterns in `.gitignore` aren't regular expressions, they're extended fnmatch/glob/wildcard patterns. Compare https://linux.die.net/man/7/glob and https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format